# building a shared library using android studio ( regarding FFMPEG/Libav Fast Fourier Transform)

Tags: android, ffmpeg, shared

I'm building some software for android and I'm desperately in need of a faster FFT function than I am currently using.

After researching I found that libav/FFMPEG have really good FFT functions tailored for the ARM architecture.

1) What is the most straight forward way to build either libraries as a .SO?
(There's so much info out there I'm overwhelmed)

2) Since I ONLY need access to the FFT, would it be possible to simple build that c class, license permitting? Last I checked there was some ARM code so that may complicate it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Actually, after doing some research it seems like an *.aar would be a better fit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a FFT lib to improve your software performance. The fastest libs right now are [fftw](https://github.com/FFTW/fftw3)  and [Ne10](https://github.com/projectNe10/Ne10). Ne10 is easier to compile. You can find the compile guide in Ne10 page building.md